# Setting Up Mulitple CheckBoxes on Userform Intialization

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

New here (first post), and pretty new to vba excel also and I have run in to a stumbling block which I'm struggling to solve. If I can find help here, then I'd be very appreciative!

I have a userform which contains 90 checkboxes. On form initialization I want to set all of the checkboxes to either TRUE or FALSE depending on a value contained within a cell on a specific sheet, which I can do, I just now have to do it for a further 89 checkboxes which, in its current format is going to be unwieldy.

I'm looking for suggestions as to how this could be achieved in a more concise way.

Thanks!

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim chRange As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim PDI_No As String
    Dim Row As Integer
    Dim rfind1 As Range
    Dim Col_Ltr1 As String

    Set ws = Worksheets("Master_Log")
    Set chRange = ws.Range("A:A")
    PDI_No = UpdateRecord.ComboBox1.Value
    Row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(PDI_No, chRange, 0) 'finds row number
    With Worksheets("Master_Log").Range("A1:DZ1")
        Set rfind1 = .find(What:=CheckBox1.Caption, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, 
                      SearchFormat:=False) 'finds column number
       Col_Ltr1 = Split((Columns(rfind1.Column).Address(, 0)), ":")(0) 'changes column number to a 
                  letter
       cellposition1 = Col_Ltr1 & Row 'range value

            If ws.Range(cellposition1) = CheckBox1.Caption Then
                CheckBox1.Value = True
                    Else
                CheckBox1.Value = False
            End If
        End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Use a loop to loop thgouh each use the value of `match` instead of find.  Are these on a form?

Comment: what is `UpdateRecord`?

Comment: Are they named as `CheckBox1`, `CheckBox2`.. .. `CheckBox90`?

Comment: BTW you know using a checked listbox is better option then using 90 checkboxes?

Comment: Use something like `Me.Controls("Checkbox" & i)` in a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this (assuming your checkboxes all have a consistent name):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim PDI_No As String
    Dim theRow, theCol, i As Long, cb As Object

    Set ws = Worksheets("Master_Log")
    PDI_No = UpdateRecord.ComboBox1.Value
    theRow = Application.Match(PDI_No, ws.Range("A:A"), 0) 'finds row number

    If Not IsError(theRow) Then
        For i = 1 To 90
            Set cb = Me.Controls("CheckBox" & i) '<<<<<
            theCol = Application.Match(cb.Caption, ws.Range("A1:DZ1"), 0)
            If Not IsError(theCol) Then
                cb.Value = (ws.Cells(theRow, theCol).Value = cb.Caption)
            Else
                'no column match
            End If
        Next i
    Else
        'no row match...
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cycle through all controls on your userform, looking for checkboxes in particular like so:

```
Private Sub CycleThroughCheckboxes
Dim x As Control
Dim r As Long
Dim result as Boolean
For Each x In UserForm1.Controls
    If TypeName(x) = "CheckBox" Then
        x.Value = true ' or false - Do your find logic here using x.Caption
    End If
Next x
End Sub
```

Benefit of doing it this way is if you add / remove some checkboxes, you don't need to keep count and change the code later on.

Comment: Thank you, I used Tim Williams code and it worked well. I will try this method when I get a chance out of interest.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the idea to trust that all 90 checkboxes are named with consecutive numbers. The following loop will loop over all controls of the form and check the type.

```
Dim ctrl As Control
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    if TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" then
        ' rest of the logic "stolen" from Ted Willams answer:
        theCol = Application.Match(ctrl.Caption, ws.Range("A1:DZ1"), 0)
        If Not IsError(theCol) Then
            ctrl.Value = (ws.Cells(theRow, theCol).Value = ctrl.Caption)
        Else
            'no column match
        End If
    End If
Next ctrl
```